# Can you close a keyboard IME programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

I have a form with three edit boxes and if the user clicks the submit button while the second text box is focused, the IME continues to show and I want to be able to hide it.

Comment: Thanks. I searched and searched for a duplicate and did not find one.